# Can't unzip a file gzipped on another server

Tags: gzip, tar, gunzip

I have main and backup servers (both with ubuntu server 12), and after gzipping a file on the main server it cannot be unzipped on the backup-one. Unzip says that file is not in gzip format. Both servers have the same gzip v1.4.

I may scp gzipped file back to main server, and there it could be successfully unzipped, so the reason is not in file transfer.

The reverse operation works, so if I gzip file on the backup server, it could be unzipped on the main one.

The question is - what should I do to define the reason of error? Verbose mode does not say anything.

Comment: I've just installed zip 3.0 on both machines, and I have the same issue with zip - file, zipped on the main server cannot be restored on the backup one. Here's what unzip says: Archive:  

End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of job.current.sql.zip or job.current.sql.zip.zip, and cannot find job.current.sql.zip.ZIP, period.

Comment: And the same is with rar. Is something wrong with line breaks or file system options?